# Getting error Main.java:4: error: <identifier> expected

Tags: java, string

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main
{
public static void find_vowels(string,vowels)
{

```
     for(int i=0;i<string.length();i++)
     {
         for (int j = 0; j < vowels.length(); j++)
         {
             if(charAt(i)==charAt(j))
             System.out.print(charAt(i)+" ");
         }
     }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("enter String");
      String string=sc.nextLine();
      String vowels="AaEeIiOoUu";
      find_vowels(string,vowels);
   }
```

}

Comment: Please explain your issue in details.

Answer (score 0):

charAt is an instance method of String class. So you need to call it on a String object i.e. string.charAt(i) == vowels.charAt(j)